# Parse complex text file for data analysis in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am a complete novice to Python-or programming.

I have a text file to parse into a CSV.  I am not able to provide an example of the text file at this time.

1. The text is several (thousand) lines with no carriage returns.
2. There are 4 types of records in the file (A, B, C, or I).
3. Each record type has a specific format based on the size of the data element.
4. There are no delimiters.
5. Immediately after the last data element in the record type, the next record type appears.
6. I have been trying to translate from a different language what this might look like in Python.

Here is an example of what I've written (not correct format)

```
file=open('TestPython.txt'), 'r' # from current working directory
dataString=file.read()
data=()
i=0
while i < len(dataString):
i = i+2
    curChar = dataString(i)
    # Need some help on the next line var curChar = dataString[i]

    if curChar = "A"
        NPI = dataString(i+1, 16) # Need to verify that is how it is done in python inside ()
            NPI.strip()
        PCN = datastring(i+17, 40)
            PCN.strip()
        seqNo = dataString(i+41, 42)
            seqNo.strip()
        MRN = dataString(i+43, 66)
            MRN.strip()
    if curChar = "B"
        NPI = dataString(i+1, 16) # Need to verify that is how it is done in python inside ()
            NPI.strip()
        PCN = datastring(i+17, 40)
            PCN.strip()
        seqNo = dataString(i+41, 42)
            seqNo.strip()
        RC1 = (i+43, 46)
            RC1.strip()
        RC2 = (i+47, 50)
            RC2.strip() 
        RC3 = (i+51, 54)
            RC3.strip()
    if curChar = "C"
        NPI = dataString(i+1, 16) # Need to verify that is how it is done in python inside ()
            NPI.strip()
        PCN = datastring(i+17, 40)
            PCN.strip()
        seqNo = dataString(i+41, 42)
            seqNo.strip()
        DXVer = (i=43, 43)
            DXVer.strip()
        AdmitDX = (i+44, 50)
            AdmitDX.strip()
        RVisit1 = (i+51, 57)
            RVisit1.strip()
```

Here's a Dummied-up version of a piece of the text file.

A     63489564696474677                 9845687                  777     67834717467764674                   TUANU             TINBUNIU    47 ERTYNU                        TDFGH                   UU748897764     66762589668777486U6764467467774767      7123609989                                                                                      9  O
    B     79466945684634677                 676756787344786474634890    7746.66                                                                                                                                                  7     96      4      7      7      9      7   774666    44969      494     7994    99666    77478   767766
    B     098765477                 64697666966667                                                                                                                                                                                9     99                                       87966    47798   797499
    C     63489564696474677                 6747494                                                7494                   7497    4964    4976    N7469   4769    N9784   9677
    I     79466944696474677                 677769U6     8888        67764674
    A     79466945684634677                 6767994                   777     696789989 6464467464764674                   UIIUN             UITTI       7747 NUU 9 ATU 4                        UANU OSASDF                   NU67479         66567896667697487U6464467476777967      7699969978            7699969978                                                                9  O

As you can see, there can be several of each type in the file.  The way this example pastes, it looks like the type is the first character on a line.  This is not the case on the actual file (i made this sample in Word).

Comment: You need to provide at least some kind of abstraction of the format or the question becomes unanswerable.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you start by pumping the entire file into a string. This is a bit wild, you should only read little bits into memory and process them.

Comment: You should possible try to use the python CSV module of python: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html, which maybe allows you to read in the data in one line...

Comment: I am not so sure this is technically speaking a CSV file.

Comment: @flup: It's not a CSV file yet. It seems to be a stream of fixed-width datasets that he wants convert into a new CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: True, but it is not exactly beginner stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You better process the file as you read it.

First, do a `file.read(1)` to determine which type of record is up next.

Then, depending on the type, read the fields, which if I understand you correctly are fixed width. So for type 'A' this would look like this:

```
def processA (file):
    NPI = file.read(16).strip()  #assuming the NPI is 16 bytes long 
    PCN = file.read(23).strip()  #assuming the PCN is 23 bytes long
    seqNo = file.read(1).strip() #assuming seqNo is 1 byte long
    MRN = file.read(23).strip()  #assuming MRN is 23 bytes long
    return {"NPI":NPI,"PCN":PCN, "seqNo":seqNo, "MRN":MRN}
```

If the file is not ASCII, there's a bit more work to get the encoding right and read characters instead of bytes.

Comment: thanks.  Yes, I was trying to turn the entire file into one string...  Wild wasn't what I was going for.  The def processA (file): looks like something to try.

Comment: When I do the file.read(1) I get an attribute error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'. Is this the text file is not ASCII?  Or do I need to hit the tutorials again (I will anyway).

Comment: No, there's a little typo when you open the file. It ought to read `file=open('TestPython.txt', 'r')`. Note the closing bracket. Your statement generates a tuple containing the open file and the 'r'.